# remove extra space at the end or start

Tags: c

this program prints matrix of any size into spiral order but the problem is that it  puts an extra space at the end of the output also,i don't want an extra space in beginning.
i could have inserted a flag inside each code to check whether they are executing first time or not and then use "%d" or "%d " accordingly but for big matrices all the if blocks will execute more than once and answer would be correctly spaced in first execution and then all without space .

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int m,n;
    int A[20][20],T,B,L,R,j,i,dir=0;
    scanf("%d%d",&m,&n);
    T=0;B=m-1;L=0;R=n-1;
    //inpu array
    for(i=0;i<m;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<n;j++)
                {
                    scanf("%d",&A[i][j]);
                }
        }

    while(T<=B && L<=R)
        {
            //right move
            if(dir==0)
                {
                    for(i=L;i<=R;i++)
                        {
                            printf("%d ",A[T][i]);
                        }
                    T++;
                    dir=1;
                 } 
            //down move
            if(dir==1)
                {
                     for(i=T;i<=B;i++)
                        {
                            printf("%d ",A[i][R]);
                        }
                    R--;
                    dir=2;
                }
            //left move
            if(dir==2)
                {
                    for(i=R;i>=L;i--)
                        {
                            printf("%d ",A[B][i]);
                        }
                    B--;
                    dir=3;
                }
            //top move
            if(dir==3)
                {
                    for(i=B;i>=T;i--)
                        {
                            printf("%d ",A[i][L]);
                        }
                    L++;
                    dir=0;
                }
        }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should indent your code. It is totally unreadable.

Comment: make a string in memory, then remove unnecessary whitespace, then print it out, instead of printing "on-the-fly"

Answer (score 1):

```
printf("%d", data[0]);
for (int i=1; i < count; i++) {
    printf(" %d", data[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may do the opposite, instead of adding an space after printing each element, add the space before each element, except in the first element. Like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
  if (i > 0) printf(" ");
  printf("%d", data[i]);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
int print_status = 0;

void print(int v){
    if(print_status)
        printf(" %d", v);
    else
        print_status = printf("%d", v);
}
```

e.g. `printf("%d ",A[i][R]);` replace to `print(A[i][R]);`